# tengo problemas con funciones de orden superior

Tags: haskell

Este es mi código, lo que necesito es que, la ultima funcion que dice mayorSegun cumpla dos requerimientos:

Debo crear una funcion mayorSegun (ya creada) donde luego por terminal le deba pasar dos funciones distintas:

1.- Saber cual itinerario es el que mas lugares visita (cual tiene mas elementos).
2.- Saber cual itinerario es el mas barato (sumo los precios y comparo).

El problema esta, en que cada vez que quiero usar en el foldl las funciones anonimas, map, (>), length; lo que sea para obtener el itinerario con mas visitas que tiene o mas barato me da error todo el santo tiempo, me dice que al comparar estoy haciendo un booleano, por ejemplo

```
mayorSegun :: (([t] -> t) -> t -> [t] -> t) -> [t] -> t
```

mayorSegun funcion listado = foldl (funcion) head(listado) listado

masVisitado :: [[Itinerario]] -> [Itinerario]
masVisitado listado = foldl (\a x -> length(x) > length a) head(listado) listado

masBarato :: [[Itinerario]] -> [Itinerario]
masBarato listado = foldl (\a x -> precioItinerario x > precioItinerario a) head(listado) listado

precioItinerario :: [Itinerario] -> Float
precioItinerario cosas = sum(map (\x -> precio x) cosas)

Esto es lo que yo hice, pero no se si esta bien, no se si hay algo que estoy gestionando mal dentro de la funcion anonima que le paso al foldl. Como puedo gestionar estas listas y poder compararlas para obtener la que deseo? siendo una lista de listas donde debo tomar cada lista dentro de esta lista superior y hacer lo dicho anteriormente.

Aclaro, no uso if, else, then, maxBy y etc... en esto, no puedo usarlo por ser algo de "facultad" donde tengo que aplicar esto, gracias desde ya.

**Código completo:**

```
-- 1)

data Itinerario =
    Restaurante String Float [String] |
    Noche String Float [String] |
    Atraccion String Float |
    Compras String Float |
    Parque String deriving Show    -- Zona, Precio, Lista cualidades

data Persona = Persona String [String] Float String Bool deriving Show    -- Nombre, Intereses, Presupuesto, Zona, Alergia

primero :: Persona
primero = Persona "Juan" [] 10000 "laBoca" False

restaurante :: Itinerario
restaurante = Restaurante "Costa Sur" 15000 ["puedeBailar", "vegano", "aptoCeliaco", "vegetariano"]
noche :: Itinerario
noche = Noche "Centro" 10000 ["puedeBailar", "musicaEnVivo"]
atraccion :: Itinerario
atraccion = Atraccion "laBoca" 1700
compras :: Itinerario
compras = Compras "Centro" 30000
parque :: Itinerario
parque =  Parque "Costa Norte"

itinerario1 :: [Itinerario]
itinerario1 = [atraccion, restaurante, compras, noche, parque]
itinerario2 :: [Itinerario]
itinerario2 = [atraccion, compras, noche, atraccion]
itinerario3 :: [Itinerario]
itinerario3 = [atraccion, restaurante, parque]
itinerario4 :: [Itinerario]
itinerario4 = [parque]

listaItinerarios :: [[Itinerario]]
listaItinerarios = [itinerario1, itinerario2, itinerario3, itinerario4]

-- 1.5)

presupuesto :: Persona -> Float
presupuesto (Persona _ _ plata _ _ ) = plata

precio :: Itinerario -> Float
precio (Restaurante _ plata _) = plata
precio (Noche _ plata _) = plata
precio (Atraccion _ plata) = plata
precio (Compras _ plata) = plata
precio (Parque _) = 0

localidad :: Persona -> String
localidad (Persona _ _ _ zona _) = zona

ubicacion :: Itinerario -> String
ubicacion (Restaurante devolver _ _) = devolver
ubicacion (Noche devolver _ _) = devolver
ubicacion (Atraccion devolver _) = devolver
ubicacion (Compras devolver _) = devolver
ubicacion (Parque devolver) = devolver


-- 2)

alcanzaPara :: Persona -> Itinerario -> Bool
alcanzaPara persona cosa = presupuesto persona > precio cosa

-- 3)

esApto :: Persona -> Itinerario -> Bool
esApto persona cosa = alcanzaPara persona cosa && cumpleCon persona cosa

cumpleCon :: Persona -> Itinerario -> Bool
cumpleCon (Persona _ intereses _ _ _) (Noche _ _ cualidades) = any (\x -> x `elem` intereses) cualidades || not (all (\x -> x `elem` intereses) cualidades)
cumpleCon (Persona _ intereses _ _ _) (Restaurante _ _ cualidades) = all(`elem` cualidades) intereses
cumpleCon persona (Compras _ _) = presupuesto persona > 20000
cumpleCon (Persona _ _ _ _ alergia) (Parque _) = not alergia
cumpleCon _ _= True

-- 4)

estaEnZona :: Persona -> Itinerario -> Bool
estaEnZona persona cosa = localidad persona == ubicacion cosa

perdidasPresupuesto :: Persona -> Itinerario -> Persona
perdidasPresupuesto (Persona nombre interes plata zona alergia) cosa = (Persona nombre interes (plata - precio cosa) zona alergia)

visitar :: Persona -> Itinerario -> Persona
visitar persona cosa 
    | esApto persona cosa && estaEnZona persona cosa = perdidasPresupuesto persona cosa
    | otherwise = persona

-- 5)

lugaresAptos :: Persona -> [Itinerario] -> [Itinerario]
lugaresAptos persona = filter (esApto persona)
-- lugaresAptos persona itinerario = [x | x <- itinerario, esApto persona x]

-- 6)

cuantosVisita :: Persona -> [Itinerario] -> Int
cuantosVisita persona itinerario = length (personaVisita persona (lugaresAptos persona itinerario))

personaVisita :: Persona -> [Itinerario] -> [Itinerario]
personaVisita persona itinerario = filter (\x -> presupuesto (visitar persona x) > 0) itinerario

-- 7)

mayorSegun :: (([t] -> t) -> t -> [t] -> t) -> [t] -> t
mayorSegun funcion listado = foldl (funcion) head(listado) listado
```

Answer (score 0):

Problema resuelto, por si a alguien le sirve a futuro:

```
mayorSegun :: ([Itinerario] -> [Itinerario] -> [Itinerario]) -> [[Itinerario]] -> [Itinerario]
mayorSegun funcion listado = foldl (funcion) (head listado) listado

-- TERMINAL
-- mayorSegun (\a x -> obtenerMayor a x) listaItinerarios
obtenerMayor :: [Itinerario] -> [Itinerario] -> [Itinerario]
obtenerMayor lista1 lista2
    | length lista1 > length lista2 = lista1
    | otherwise = lista2

-- mayorSegun (\a x -> obtenerMasBarato a x) listaItinerarios
obtenerMasBarato :: [Itinerario] -> [Itinerario] -> [Itinerario]
obtenerMasBarato lista1 lista2
    | obtener < obtener2 = lista1
    | otherwise = lista2
    where obtener = sum(map precio lista1); obtener2 = sum(map precio lista2)
```

Comment: No olvides describir tu respuesta. Lee [answer] y pulsa en [edit] para mejorarla.